# Ruby script step in Mac Automator workflow does not exit

Tags: macos, mac, automator, ruby

I have created an Automator workflow in Mac OS X 10.5.8.  The workflow is supposed to run a Ruby script and then shutdown the computer.

The Ruby script copies files between several computers and then sends an email when complete.  When I run the script in Automator all code is executed with out errors, because I get the email and all the files are copied, but the Automator step running the script never exits so the computer never shuts down.  I have tested the shutdown step independently and it works fine.

The Ruby script takes around 20 minutes to complete.  If I cut the script down so it just sends the email and executes in less then 10 seconds, the Automator workflow executes all the way and the computer shuts down.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added [exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005930) function to the end of the ruby script.  Now the shell script step finishes correctly in Automator and then runs the AppleScript to shutdown the computer.